# angularjs text editors with input keywords are colored

Tags: html, angularjs

What i want to do is in angularjs text editor like [this](http://textangular.com/), if entered text is a keyword then it should be colored otherwise it should be normal in the text editor.

Please help me how to achieve this and mention which editors and frameworks should use, how to achieve that task.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ng-bind='CheckText()'** in your text box

CheckText function is check every written text if it matches the keyword you will add HTML tags e.g. Keyword

and this span will take CSS class